# Migrating Grape API to standard Rails API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, grape-api

I'm looking to migrate from an API that was built in Grape to a straight Rails API.  I've been looking for some resources on the best practises to do so and have come up quite empty. I was wondering if anyone has any good resources/tips/tricks or anything else that may be of help to me in this process?

Comment: The trick is to read the documentation for both of them and match up calls. Do you have any external API tests that can verify your API is still working correctly?